# Capacitor in series?

Tags: electricity, electrostatics, capacitance

Say you have two charged capacitors in series. Zoom in on one capacitor. For this specific capacitor, the charge on the two plates will be the same in magnitude, according to my textbook.

My teacher said that the charge on the two plates won't be the same if the gap between the the plates is large. In fact, the charge on each plate in a capacitor is *never* the same. They're only approximated to be the same if the gap is small.

Why is the charge not the same on both plates on a capacitor in series if the gap is large?

[image]

Comment: What is your teacher's source for the (rather odd) claim that the charges on a capacitor's plates are not equal?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Well, my textbook gives the following explanation: Let us assume that there are 2 capacitors connected in series by a battery, capacitor 1 consists of plates A and B and capacitor 2 consists of plates C and D. The plates are lined up in series alphabetically. The battery will cause a buildup of charge of +q on plate A and -q on plate D. The charge of +q on plate A will attract a charge of -q on plate B and the charge of -q on plate D will attract a charge of +q on plate C. Therefore the charge will be the same on all plates.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft My teachers argument was the following. Refer to the diagram. Assume the gap between plate A and B is large. Assume the battery has caused a build up of charge of +q on plate A. Now the electrons in the wire connecting plate B and plate C will be attracted towards plate A because of plate A's charge. The attraction will stop when plate B has a *slightly less* buildup of charge, since plate B is closer to the electrons in the connecting wire.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Essentially his argument is that the charged plates will not attract an equal and opposite charge.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the electric field between the capacitor plates bulges out at the edges (the "fringing field").  If the arrangement of the external conductors is not symmetrical around the two plates, some of the field lines from one plate can "escape" from the capacitor structure and wind up terminating on an external conductor.

Since field lines terminate on charges (via Poisson's law), this asymmetry in the field implies an imbalance in the plate charges.

The wider the plate spacing (relative to the plate length and width), the more field lines can escape, and so the greater the imbalance.

Note, however, that an asymmetry in the geometry is required; otherwise, the plate charges will balance regardless of their spacing, because the field lines will be symmetrical for a symmetrical geometry.

Thinking about this "symmetry" aspect a bit more, I see that I've left something out.  I could imagine a third electrode that was geometrically symmetrical with respect to the two plates but that nevertheless unbalanced the electric fields because its potential was set asymmetrically (e.g. a "guard ring" encircling the plates that was set to the potential of one of the plates).  Only if the third conductor's potential is set midway between those of the plates is the balance restored.  So the symmetry must extend to the voltages of the conductors and not just their geometry.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain why the plate charges balance if the geometry is symmetrical?

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by geometry?

Comment: The geometry includes the sizes of the various conductors, their locations, and their arrangements.

Comment: When you say "conductors", do you mean the conducting plates of the capacitor or do you mean the conducting wire?

Comment: In your figure, the conductors are the wires, plus plates C and D.  (But if plates A and B were not identical, they would also break the symmetry.)